# System.Management.ManagementException "Access Denied" with Win32_ProcessStartTrace

Tags: c#, managementeventwatcher

I have a piece of code to handle scenarios where specific processes are started or stopped and in order to achieve this I am using ManagementEventWatcher.

```
       string queryStart = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace" +
                     " WHERE ProcessName LIKE '...'"; // WHERE clause includes all the processnames that I want to monitor 
       ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
            new WqlEventQuery(queryStart));
        startWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(ProcessNewInstanceWhenCreated);
        startWatch.Start();
```

This code works fine locally on my machine but when I deploy it to one of the servers it throw "Access denied" exception. The user running this on the server does not have admin rights and accordingly I added the user as explained in this link - http://world.episerver.com/faq/Items/SystemManagementManagementException-Access-denied/

This doesnt seem to solve the problem. Do I have perform any other action to get this to work on the server?

I added a ManagementScope to the ManagementEventHandler as well but still doesnt help the cause.

```
       string scopeString = "\\\\" + System.Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\CIMV2";
        ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope(scopeString);
        ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(theScope,
            new WqlEventQuery(queryStart));
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Spying on starting processes is a security risk, the program must run elevated.  Add the [required manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034).

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in getting events with process names and ids without admin privileges using the following query:

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN .025 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";
processWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(@"\\.\root\CIMV2", queryString);
processWatcher.EventArrived += ProcessStartHandler;
processWatcher.Start();
```

Unlike the query you were using, the event received doesn't have most of its properties filled.

However, they are accessible through the event's TargetInstance property.

```
private void ProcessStartHandler(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    var targetInstance = ((System.Management.ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value);
    var processName = targetInstance.Properties["Caption"].Value.ToString();
    var processId   = (uint)targetInstance.Properties["ProcessId"].Value;
    var parentProcessId = (uint)targetInstance.Properties["ParentProcessId"].Value;
}
```